# LARAVEL: passing data from database to view with controller and model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

Okay, I'm creating a store for baby stuff with a scraper. At this moment I've programmed that a user can create multiple lists (lists will be closed after some months but they won't be deleted). When you click on a specific list, it wil open and the first thing you'll see is an h2 that says "this is the list of ***name of the baby*** . But that name should be dynamic and even tho I'm using laravel for a couple weeks, this little things should be easy for me but it's not.. The point is. Because I am on a specific list, I can't use a foreach loop and those are the only solutions I saw from others. I just have my models and my controllers..

My migration:

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique;
            $table->binary('password');
            $table->enum('role', ['user','admin'])->default('user');
            $table->timestamp('created_at');
            $table->timestamp('updated_at');
        });

        Schema::create('lists', function (Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->foreignId('user_id')->nullable()->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->string('baby');
            $table->string('vader');
            $table->string('moeder');
            $table->integer('telefoonnummer');
            $table->string('email');
            $table->string('adres');
            $table->integer('huisnummer');
            $table->string('toevoeging')->nullable();
            $table->string('stad');
            $table->integer('postcode');
            $table->string('land');
        });
    }
```

My User model:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array<string, string>
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function birthLists()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Birthlist::class);
    }
}
```

My Birthlist model:

```
class Birthlist extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected  $table = 'lists';

    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    protected $fillable = 
    [
        'user_id',
        'baby',
        'vader',
        'moeder',
        'telefoonnummer',
        'email',
        'adres',
        'huisnummer',
        'toevoeging',
        'stad',
        'postcode',
        'land'
    ];

    public $timestamps = false;

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
    }
}
```

My controller

```
<?php 

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Birthlist;



class BabyController extends Controller
{
    public function show($id, $baby) 
    {
        $name = Birthlist::all();
        return view('babylist')->with('name');
    }

}
```

My view (Where it says:{{$name->name}} should come the name of the baby )

```
@include('partials.header')
<body class="relative min-h-screen">
    <main class="w-full p-2 md:w-2/3 md:m-auto bg-red-100">
        <div>
            <h2>Deze lijst is van <strong>{{$name->name}}</strong></h2>
        </div>
    </main>
</body>
@include('partials.footer')
```

Comment: `$name` is a [collection](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#collections) of all of the baby lists. You'll need to iterate through it using a `@foreach` loop

Comment: Okay, but how can I get the specific list? because with a foreach, I'm going through all of them right?

Comment: [`Birthlist::find($id);`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#retrieving-single-models) or `Birthlist::whereUserId($id)->whereBaby($baby)->first()`, depending on what those variables are

Comment: So if I write that in my controller, I still have to use the foreach loop?

Comment: No, the foreach loop is only for a collection of multiple results.

Comment: that is what I did, but can I retrieve the data with this code: {{$name->baby}}